# Node.js mysql Q; what's the best way to wait for query to finish

Tags: node.js

First of all i feel embarrassed that still don't fully understand callbacks in Javascript. My simple code supposes to wait for mysql query to finish and then send back to web client, but out of order now.
This is what i'm seeing:

step 3: undefined

step 1:  John

step 2:  [ 'John' ]

Q1: Other than async, any better ways i can do in  app.get('/db1') ?

Q2: in db.js, is async necessary? i do see samples do connect/query/end without async, but thought this is file io ?

main.js

```
const express = require('express')  
const app = express()  
const port = 8080

var db1 = require("./db.js");

app.get('/', (request, response) => {  
  response.send('Hello from Express!')
})

app.get('/db1', (request, response) => {  
   var q1 = db1.query1();
   console.log("step 3: " + q1);
   response.send('Hello from db1! ' + q1);
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {  
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }
  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

db.js

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var async      = require('async');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '123.abc',
  database : 'mydb'
});

var query1 = function() { 
    var q1 = "NA";

    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            connection.connect();

            connection.query('SELECT * from customer;', 
                             function(err, rows, fields) {
              if (err){
                  console.log("---- Not supposed to see this -----");
                  callback(true);
              }

              q1 = rows[0].name; 
              console.log('step 1: ', rows[0].name);
              callback(null, q1);
            });

          },
        ], 
        function(err, result) {
            connection.end();
            if(err) {
                return "NA";
            } else {
                console.log("step 2: ", result);
                return result[0].name;
            }
         }
    );
};

module.exports = {
    query1: query1
};
```

Comment: You can pass calbacks directly without the `async` library.

Comment: @SLaks, when i do this app.get('/db1', (request, response) => {  
   var q1 = db1.query1(function(){
       console.log("step 3: " + q1);
       response.send('Hello from db1! ' + q1);
   });
})
i never see "step 3", web basically hangs, any suggestions ? thx !

Comment: You're passing the wrong parameters to `query`.  See its documentation.